# Can't get Facebook ID and email

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-authentication

I faced with the following problem: I need to get FB id and email after authorization. Here's my code:

```
@Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                final String[] email = new String[1];
                final String[] id = new String[1];

                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        (object, response) -> {
                            try {
                                email[0] = object.getString(FB_EMAIL_PERMISSION);
                                id[0] = object.getString(FB_ID_PERMISSION);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            response.getRawResponse();
                        });

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,email");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString(EXTRA_TOKEN, loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
                bundle.putString(EXTRA_EMAIL, email[0]);
                bundle.putString(EXTRA_ID, id[0]);

                mPresenter.saveUserData(bundle);
            }
```

But when I run my app, I don't get this fields. I checked in debugger and part

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        (object, response) -> {
                            try {
                                email[0] = object.getString(FB_EMAIL_PERMISSION);
                                id[0] = object.getString(FB_ID_PERMISSION);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            response.getRawResponse();
                        });
```

isn't called at all. I don't understand why it happens. So, what's the matter and how can I solve it?

**UPD**

Probably, maybe it would help, here's whole fb logic:

```
mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        mFacebookButton.setReadPermissions(Collections.singletonList(FB_EMAIL_PERMISSION));
        mFacebookButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                final String[] email = new String[1];
                final String[] id = new String[1];

                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        (object, response) -> {
                            try {
                                email[0] = object.getString(FB_EMAIL_PERMISSION);
                                id[0] = object.getString(FB_ID_PERMISSION);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            response.getRawResponse();
                        });

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,email");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString(EXTRA_TOKEN, loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
                bundle.putString(EXTRA_EMAIL, email[0]);
                bundle.putString(EXTRA_ID, id[0]);

                mPresenter.saveUserData(bundle);
            }
```

**UPD 2**

I have one think about this problem, that request is asynchronous and when I put a breakpoint on line `mPresenter.saveUserData(bundle);` information isn't loaded yet, but how can I make it synchronous? Or maybe I am wrong?

**UPD 3**

I changed my request in the following way, but it still doesn't work and breakpoints are skipped in this part.

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        (object, response) -> {
                            try {
                                if (response.getJSONObject() != null) {
                                    JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                                    if (data.has(FB_EMAIL_PERMISSION)) {
                                        email[0] = response.getJSONObject().getString(FB_EMAIL_PERMISSION);
                                    }
                                    if (data.has(FB_ID_PERMISSION)) {
                                        id[0] = response.getJSONObject().getString(FB_ID_PERMISSION);
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            response.getRawResponse();
                        });
```

And here's the values of permissions:

```
private static final String FB_EMAIL_PERMISSION = "email";
private static final String FB_ID_PERMISSION = "id";
```

Answer (score 1):

did you add permission to your facebook login button

```
fbLoginButton.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile,email,user_birthday"));
```

Comment: I had this line:         `mFacebookButton.setReadPermissions(Collections.singletonList(FB_EMAIL_PERMISSION));`, but when I added your variant it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: setReadPermissions is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

this is how i am using it 
i am not sure of the value of `FB_EMAIL_PERMISSION` `FB_ID_PERMISSION`

```
 final GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject object,
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        try {
                            String id = "", user_email = "", name = "";
                            Log.d("EHREIUIU", String.valueOf(object));
                            if (response.getJSONObject() != null) {
                                JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                                if (data.has("id"))
                                    id = data.getString("id");
                                if (data.has("email"))
                                    user_email = data.getString("email");
                            }
                            getOneSignalToken();
                            socialLogin(user_email, name, null, id, "facebook");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Updated the question